# Отсутствие запятых перед "и" в сложноподчиненном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, союзы, и

Предложение:
**В такие летние сумерки хорошо выйти в сухие сени, в низкие комнаты с только что вымытыми полами, где уже горят лампы(1) и за открытыми окнами шумит от падающих капель(2) и дико пахнет заброшенный сад.**

Почему на месте цифр 1 и 2 не должны стоять запятые? Объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78354/discussion-on-question-by------).

Comment: Пожалуйста, отметьте данный ответ галочкой, если он оказался полезным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А – главное предложение (В такие летние сумерки хорошо выйти в сухие сени, в низкие комнаты с только что вымытыми полами);
Б1 – первое придаточное (**где** уже горят лампы);
Б2 – второе придаточное (**[где]** за открытыми окнами шумит от падающих капель и дико пахнет заброшенный сад).

1. Запятая перед одиночным союзом **(1) и** не ставится, т. к придаточные предложения Б1 и Б2 имеют **общее главное предложение А**.
2. Запятая перед одиночным союзом **(2) и** в предложении Б2 не ставится, т. к. он находится между **однородными сказуемыми** *шумит* и *пахнет* [сад].

[**Запятая перед союзом И**](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/315-zapyatayaperedsyuzomi.html)

Answer (score 4):

[В такие летние сумерки хорошо выйти в сухие сени, в низкие комнаты с только что вымытыми полами],(где уже горят лампы) (1) и (за открытыми окнами шумит от падающих капель (2) и дико пахнет заброшенный сад).

Сложноподчинённое предложение с двумя придаточными, соединёнными однородной связью (где горят лампы и шумит и пахнет сад), поэтому нет запятой на месте первых скобок перед одиночным союзом И. На месте цифры 2 нет запятой, потому что одиночный союз  И соединяет однородные сказуемые шумит и пахнет.